# Erro com angularJS com $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou tentando buscar alguns dados via WS(Web Service) só que quando peço pra retornar no meu app dá este erro:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Mas quando tento buscar via console ele retorna normalmente.

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ionic']);

//listar clientes via ws somente ativos

App.get('ListaCtrl', function($scope, $http){
   $http.post('http:// meu url da ws').
       success(function (data) {
           $scope.ret = data;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você está consumindo dados de outros domínios, é necessário que seja liberado no WS o acesso de domínios externos para que funcione. Por padrão, os navegadores e servidores bloqueiam o acesso que não seja do mesmo domínio para evitar invasões.

Outro método que pode ser visto, é fazer com que a requisição enviada seja no formato JSONP, que na maioria dos WebServices já vem liberado como padrão... No caso do AngularJS usado acima (nota-se pelo `$http.get`) você pode fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo:

```
$http.get({
  url : '/api/contest/submit.action', 
  data : { params: $param, responseType: 'jsonp' }
});
```

**NOTA** Aqui está uma solução, não testei ainda mas provavelmente deve funcionar...

[Enable CORS with AngularJS](http://www.code-sample.com/2015/02/enabling-cors-in-angularjs.html)